# Angularjs - How to show by default first tab of accordion in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, accordion, show-hide

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="x in records">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  ng-click="showCompAcc=!showCompAcc" showtab="">{{x.Name}}</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div  ng-hide="showCompAcc" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">dfdfdfd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is snippet of accordion with ng-repeat data.Currently It showing all tabs. What I want is by default it should show only first tab open and on click of other tab it should get  display other tab details and hide the default tab details.

Comment: You can add `ng-class=::{'ng-hide': $index > 0}` - It will add `ng-hide` class to each tab that is not the first (Index == 0) - You can also do `ng-class=::{'ng-hide': $index}` (Shorthand version)

Comment: It will be great if you could provide snippet. I have attached working snippet above. @AlonEitan

Comment: I added full example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use uib-accordion provided by angular ui bootstrap

[Angular ui accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion)

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany",
      "open" : true
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden",
      "open": false
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico",
      "open" : false
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria",
      "open" : false
    }
  ]
```

HTML

```
    <uib-accordion close-others="true"> 
     <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{group.Name}}" ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">

     {{group.Country}}
     </div>
   </uib-accordion>
```

Here is plunker for this.
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5l6g8zRw9Xe2uvkXrtMv?p=preview)

Check it out

Comment: It showing this error, https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$$isDocumentHiddenProvider%20%3C-%20$$isDocumentHidden%20%3C-%20$$animateQueue%20%3C-%20$animate%20%3C-%20$compile%20%3C-%20$$animateQueue.  @nishantagarwal

Comment: @Mohammed
It is working fine in plunker. It Seems like it is unable to resolve animate dependency. 
This error is in the plunker or in your code?

Comment: Its now working fine, except by default first tab open. @nishantagarwal

Comment: @Mohammed Read about the `is-open` property in the documentation link provided in nishant's answer

Comment: Yes, I found that in @nishantagrawal plunkr, he has set is-open to false except first and that is why first is by default open,  but in my case, data is coming from back end, so I cant apply is-open property to all the objects, How to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `ng-class=::{'ng-hide': $index > 0}` to the body of each tag.

It will add `ng-hide` class (that is basically css with `display: none;`) to each tab body which is not the first (Index == 0) - You can also do `ng-class=::{'ng-hide': $index}` (Shorthand version).

I also added `ng-init="showCompAcc = $index > 0"` that will set the `showCompAcc` flag correctly for each tab when you click on it.

The `::` is a one-time binding for making sure that it will set the class just as the template render, and not reset the class on every digest cycle.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="x in records" >
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-click="showCompAcc=!showCompAcc" showtab="">{{x.Name}}</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div  ng-hide="showCompAcc" ng-init="showCompAcc = $index > 0" ng-class="::{'ng-hide': $index}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">dfdfdfd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

If you want to hide the current open tab when you click on other tab you can do the following:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp2", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.active = {record: 0};
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="x in records">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-click="active.record = $index">{{x.Name}}</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div  ng-if="active.record == $index" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">dfdfdfd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here I added a flag on the controller

```
$scope.active = {
    record: 0
};
```

Which holds the default tab index in the `records` array, and i'm updating it in the `ng-click="active.record = $index"` with the clicked tab. Next, we show the active tab body using `ng-if="active.record == $index"`.

Comment: Thanks for this.But this is not working: on click of other tab it should get display other tab details and hide the default tab details or tab which is open. @AlonEitan

Comment: @Mohammed What doesn't work? Tell me and i'll edit my answer

Comment: I just comment. @AlonEitan

Comment: @Mohammed I added my answer f

Comment: It working fine here, but when I am implementing this in my project, its not showing any tabs?  @AlonEitan

Comment: @Mohammed It's hard to guess what's the problem in your project without the code, but I suggest to implement it using the other answer provided by  nishant.

Comment: yes, I used second answer, except that by default problem everything works fine.